# Cross area calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have an asp.net mvc 2 application with multiple areas .  Each area contains its own nested master page.

Some times we need one area to use the partial functionality from the other area.

Ex: "Account area" contains a feature for managing all user's contacts.  "Job area" wants to borrow contacts feature, but just for work contacts.

We cannot simply redirect from one area to other, as this will change the visual context for the user.  We want the features of the second area to appear as if they belong to the first area.

Is there any clean way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

your Partial functionality implemenetd using partial pages? then You can cosnider to add these partial pages in shared folder.

Comment: Well, this path forces me to create duplicate code in the form of controllers, actions, views that call those partial views in both the areas.